# WPF Datagrid with cell Material Design PackIcon

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid, mahapps.metro

I'm trying to populate a datagrid with several columns generated in c#.  One of the columns will be a PackIcon or PackIconMaterial and another a checkbox with several text columns. The image will change depending on an int value in the data collection.

```
<DataGrid Name="DataGrid1"/>
</DataGrid>

Code to populate the grid:

ObservableCollection<DemoModel> models = new ObservableCollection<DemoModel>();
models.Add(new DemoModel() { Text = "Some Text #1.", DynamicImg = PackIconKind.Bell });
models.Add(new DemoModel() { Text = "Some Text #2." });
models.Add(new DemoModel() { Text = "Some Text #3." });
models.Add(new DemoModel() { Text = "Some Text #4.", DynamicImg = PackIconKind.BellOutline});
models.Add(new DemoModel() { Text = "Some Text #5." });
DataGrid1.ItemsSource = models;


The model:

class DemoModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    protected String _text;
    public String Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _text = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Text"); }
    }

    protected String _dynamicText;

    public String DynamicText
    {
        get { return _dynamicText; }
        set { _dynamicText = value; RaisePropertyChanged("DynamicText"); }
    }

    internal bool MyIsReadOnly = true;

    protected PackIconKind _DynamicImg;
    public PackIconKind DynamicImg
    {
        get { return _DynamicImg; }
        set {
            _DynamicImg = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("DynamicImg");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler temp = PropertyChanged;
        if (temp != null)
        {
            temp(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

All I get with this code is text "Bell" or "BellOutline". I have also tried "public PackIcon DynamicImg" but that seemed to just display the class name rather than an image in the cell.

Has anybody got a complete example?  I've looked at a few examples but none really complete working with mahapps icons.

Using .Net 4.6 and Material Design Themes 2.3.1.953.

Thanks in advance,
Steve

Answer (score 1):

I think what would work is setting the DataGrid's AutoGenereateColumnts property to false and defining them in XAML. If you defined one column's template to be a PackIcon you could then bind the PackIcon kind to it.

Here's and example:

The DataGrid in XAML

```xml
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Icon">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="{Binding IconKind}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

The MainWindow code behind

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = this;

            Items.Add(new Item
            {
                Name = "Printer",
                IconKind = PackIconKind.Printer
            });

            Items.Add(new Item
            {
                Name = "AbTesting",
                IconKind = PackIconKind.AbTesting
            });

            Items.Add(new Item
            {
                Name = "GoogleHome",
                IconKind = PackIconKind.GoogleHome
            });
        }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public PackIconKind IconKind { get; set; }
    }
```

Cheers, Michal.